# Loading google maps breaks css/stylesheet

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple application which uses google maps. In particular I am using the `AgmCoreModule` and the `places` library:

```js
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: '*********************',
  libraries: ['places']
}),
```

Everything is working fine except that navigating to the page where the module is being loaded, I notice that my stylesheet is getting messed up. Things like

```xml
<b>My text</b>
```

Do not look the same anymore.

Just navigating to the page changes everything from

[image]

to this:

[image]

It looks like the font changes too.

Any idea how I can avoid this behavior?

---

**Update:**

I noticed that as I go to the page where I am loading google maps, that there is a GET request to https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700. I assume that this is the root of the problem.

Is there a way to prevent google maps from doing this?

Comment: Hi! Is it possible to create a minimal repro on stackblitz?

Comment: @alt255 I'm quite busy at the moment but I will try to provide one tomorrow - worst case scenario next week since I'll be gone for a few days. I've tested it. So far I am seeing this happening on Chrome but *not* on Firefox. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue (https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1466).

There is a workaround which just prevents google maps from downloading the additional fonts:

```
<script>
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    // Save the original method
    var insertBefore = head.insertBefore;

    // Replace it!
    head.insertBefore = function (newElement, referenceElement) {

        if (newElement.href && newElement.href.indexOf('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto') > -1) {

            console.info('Prevented Roboto from loading!');
            return;
        }

        insertBefore.call(head, newElement, referenceElement);
    };
</script>
```